# dataset in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have tried to use Dataset in Silverlight Application. But I'm not able to create dataset object. Please give me a solution for this.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight only has a subset of the .NET framework features, and DataSets are not part of this subset...

However there is a third party implementation of datasets for Silverlight [here](http://silverlightdataset.net/silverlightdataset/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight does not support Datasets. See here for a discussion about alternatives: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/23300/82701.aspx